# how to show a image for HTML type?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I create an autocomplete search box and I get product name and I want to get product photo but I did not do it. There is my code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtContactsSearch" runat="server" Width="261"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="Search11" 
    MinimumPrefixLength="1"
    CompletionInterval="10"
    EnableCaching="false"
    CompletionSetCount="10" 

    TargetControlID="txtContactsSearch"
    ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected = "true">
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

**Web Service Code:**

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> Search11(string prefixText, int count)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["U"].ToString();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select Top(10) * from S  WITH (NOLOCK) where  KeySentences like @SearchText + '%'  ";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            List<string> Search = new List<string>();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    //"<img src='st4.abc.com.tr/img/urun/p_" + sdr["RecID"].ToString()+"_01_01.jpg' />" + " " 
                    Search.Add( sdr["KeySentences "].ToString().Substring(0, 30));
                    Search.Add("<img style = 'height:30px;width:30px' src = 'st4.abc.com.tr/img/urun/p_"+sdr["RecID"].ToString()+"_01_01.jpg'");
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
            return Search;
        }
    }
}
```

I can get product name but image is not. It seems:

[image]

I want to show only picture not HTML text.I think I use script or something like but I dont know  What can I do for this?  Thanks for your answers

Comment: Remove the spaces between the attributes (like src="" instead of src = '') and close the image: + '/ >'. Also, I am now quite sure if you can display images in there. It is a div?

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I remove the spaces and add close tag but its not solution, same situation is cont

Answer (score 0):

the required functionality can be achieved by referring the following article

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Render-images-in-autocomplete-list-of-ASP.Net-AJAX-AutoCompleteExtender.aspx

Comment: thanks for your answer I can use it but i dont understand some part of code for example i get ID number from database like:  sdr["EmployeeId"].ToString()  but how can I show a link with this ID on HTML like: <img style = 'height:30px;width:30px' src = 'st4.abc.com.tr/img/urun/p_"+sdr["EmployeeId"].ToString()+"_01_01.jpg' In this example using static url not dynamic, I want to use dynamic